# Dynamic CSS from JSON for each element

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, dynamic-css

I have got an element in API that need to be render dynamically and the style of the element is given like below

```
"elementStyle": {
              "Width": "100",
              "Height": "100",
              "ThemeSize": "M",
              "TopMargin": "0",
              "LeftMargin": "0",
               "Background" : "#EEEEE",
               font : "roboto"
            },
```

What would be the best way of mapping key like Background to background-color and font to font-family Topmargin to margin-top.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you saved the json to a scope variable like e.g. `$scope.myElementStyle` you could apply the styles to the dom element like this:

```
<div ng-style="{'background-color':myElementStyle.Background, 'font-family':myElementStyle.font}"></div>
```

Comment: my question is related to How do you know that background-color property need to be applied for Background because I have every key is dynamic.

Comment: I am sorry, but i can not fully understand your problem. It would be best if you could rename the properties in the json according to their css equivalents! There are too many css styles to generate an individual mapping for your purpose i guess...